# how to pass variables to templates only for some applications

Tags: django

I have a django project, with a lot of applications. Now i need to add some variables to the context dictionary only for some applications.Does django provide any option to achieve this?
I know decorator can be helpful.Is there any other way,like a middleware / context processor that runs automatically but only for specific applications.

Comment: Assuming each of Django apps has its own views, the answer is "yes". Just alter the context on a per view basis, or subclass context class and use it within the application. But I tend to think you should re-think your approach and whether this is really necessary.

Comment: Do the values of the variables depend on the view? Otherwise you can indeed write a context processor that only adds values for certain requests.

Comment: no the values dont depend on views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context processor like this can do what you need:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def app_var(request):
    if resolve(request.path).app_name == 'YOUR_APP_NAME':
        return {'CUSTOM_VAR': 'VALUE'}
    return {}
```

to install the context processor, put the code in any file you like, and add a entry referencing (e.g. `'folder.file.app_var'`) it in the `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: but a context processor's scope is throughout the project...i want for applications

Comment: the if in the first line is to limit its scope to a certain application, just put your application name instead of 'YOUR_APP_NAME'.

Comment: Work arounds are always there. The main reason for the question is to identify if thers a feature in django itself.